# How to get hrefs from from elements with a certain class through CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I've got a web page with information in this format:

```
<p>
    <a class="class1" href="href1">text1</a>
    text2
</p>

<p>
    <a class="class1" href="href2">text1a</a>
    text2a
</p>
```

Using CasperJS, I need to get an array of all the information contained in just in elements with *class1* in this format:

```
href1
text1
text2

href2
text1a
text2a
```

I've tried using this code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('url', function() {
    require('utils').dump(this.getElementsAttribute('div[class="class1"]', 
          'class'));
});
casper.run();
```

However, I just got a '[ ]' as an answer.

Can anybody help me find the error in my code?

Comment: It's simple text, sorry for not be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div[class="class1"]` as a selector cannot work, because you don't have any `<div>` elements in your markup that have the `class1` class. You can try the following, but it won't get you far:

```
this.getElementsAttribute('a.class1', 'href');
```

## Building an array of objects in the page context

It is hard and may be error prone to do this only with CasperJS functions. It is much easier to do this by iterating over all the links and fetching the parts that you need.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var info = this.evaluate(function(){
        var links = document.querySelectorAll(".class1");
        // iterate over links and collect stuff
        return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link){
            return {
                href: link.href,
                hrefText: link.textContent.trim(),
                afterText: link.parentNode.childNodes[2].textContent.trim()
            };
        });
    });
    require('utils').dump(info);
});
```

**How this works:**

You can get all the links by querying all for all the elements with `class1`. Since the result of `querySelectorAll()` is not an array, but an array-like NodeList, you can't directly use `.map()` on it.

Each link has a `href` property and a `textContent` property. The text after the link is a little tricky. You first need to get the parent of the link (`<p>`) and then try to get the TextNode after the link by accessing the `childNodes` property.

`childNodes[2]` must probably be used instead of `childNodes[1]`, because the first (`childNodes[0]`) is probably a TextNode containing whitespace, so everything after it shifts.

## Building a single string in the page context

You can also iterate over it to get it in a textual representation:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var info = this.evaluate(function(){
        var links = document.querySelectorAll(".class1");
        // iterate over links and collect stuff
        return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link){
            return [
                link.href,
                link.textContent.trim(),
                link.parentNode.childNodes[2].textContent.trim()
            ].join('\n');
        }).join('\n\n');
    });
    this.echo(info);
});
```

**How it works:**

JavaScript arrays have a [`join()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). It can joins every element using the specified separator.

---

Keep in mind that the page context (`evaluate()`) is sandboxed. The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) says:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Comment: Iterate over `info` to create an output that you want.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Artjom B for your fast answer. 
1.- In order to help other newbies, I edited the cuestion to reflect "text" instead of "objects". 
2.- I got all the information, except the text after the link. Childnotes just get the same as text1 or text1a.

Comment: Yes, the first childNode is most likely an empty TextNode. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now I got nothing in screen. Let me check. I'm trying to write the actual code here but I can't format it.

Comment: `evaluate()` is not a step function, so it must be inside of a `then*` or `wait*` function like in the first snippet

Comment: gist:3924d0fddd2bee70c33a

Comment: Still nothing in screen. Code as it is now:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f08d81575e80f97eb1e0

Comment: don't forget `casper.run();` at the end otherwise the queue isn't started.

Comment: Ok. Now is running. But I still can´t get text2. It copies text1.

Comment: Ok, this is what is happening, and sorry for not be clear since the beginning: 

Aftertext brings:
text4,text2 - text1

So, in fact, it's not repeating. It's bringing what it founds. 
I just need to extract text 2 (after the comma and before the '-')

Comment: I see no reason why that would be the case. Maybe your markup doesn't match with the real markup. Play around with the objects, maybe you find how it differs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your work and patience. I'll paste the final code after I finished.